# Presto map<varchar,set<varchar>> : How to query a field in presto which is of type map<varchar,set<varchar>>

Tags: cassandra, presto, map-function

I am trying to search a column having the data type `map<varchar,set<varchar>>`. I keep getting  `Query failed (#20190809_163618_00200_yyc4a) in your-presto: null`
Any help is appreciated.

The below query is working perfectly

```
SELECT event_type_id FROM cassandra.data_integration_hub.my_table WHERE event_type_id = 123 limit 5
```

when I add business_keys field, the query is failing

```
SELECT event_type_id,business_keys FROM cassandra.data_integration_hub.my_table WHERE event_type_id = 123 limit 5
```

The business_keys is of type

Type: `map<varchar,set<varchar>>`

Sample Value:

```
{
  "rule_id" : [ "12345" ]
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the Cassandra connector.  Can file an issue with the full stack trace at https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues?  Also, maybe ask on Slack: https://prestosql.io/community.html

Answer (score 0):

`Query failed (#20190809_163618_00200_yyc4a) in your-presto: null` -- this is the (odd) way how Cassandra connector would report "column type not supported".

We improved error reporting since then and extended support for certain types in the Cassandra connector. Please try Presto 317 or Starburst Presto 312e.